# Order confirmation email align it to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, email-templates

In my spree app site, when the user purchases an item, I am sending an order confirmation email.

The email when opened is aligned on the left instead of center.

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/sJVNga6F) the email template code which I am using.

I am not sure what do I do to make it open in the center.

Although while starting the table, I have given the align property like below.

```
 <table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Please help.

Comment: You should post a picture of the email so that we can see how it looks like to help you better.

Comment: [here's](http://imgur.com/a/g5XkH) the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

It helps me:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            Content
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Where you have "Content" if it is a table, set it to the desired width and you will have centred content.

Comment: @SurajShukla In which browser you have got this result?

Comment: I am checking it on Chrome.

Comment: @SurajShukla Try to clear the browser's cache and open the email on any email client ( thunderbird - for instance )

Comment: @SurajShukla From a technical point of view, this is one of the most popular solutions for design email ( my post above ). You are doing something wrong

Comment: Artem, I have already cleared the cache and checked. 

Can you just take a look at the snippet which I have shared.

Comment: @SurajShukla Already. It works for me and some people ( i shared it with comrads ).

Comment: @SurajShukla By the way - You forgot to close BODY tag

Comment: @SurajShukla Maybe problem hiding in this case ( BODY )